# [Azure Mobile App Service]How to login without password on Facebook sign-in?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I activated Facebook sign-in with Azure's Mobile App Service, but the service asked to enter an ID and password.

Instagram or other famous application can login without entering the password as "Continue as a Name" if it is already logged in to FaceBook.

I would like to authenticate Facebook on Azure without entering ID or password, how can I do it?

Comment: which authentication flow ([Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) or [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow)) you use? And what is the platform of your client for test this issue? I just tested this issue via browser, it could work as expected.

Comment: Could you show the "OAuth client authorization settings" of your facebook app? Have you check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow/) about testing Facebook login process?

Comment: @BruceChen Thank you for responding.This occurs on Mobile (iPhone / Android). like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNrpr1vAPmY

Comment: @BruceChen I'm not sure , but this may be  Server-managed authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow), your app would authenticate the user through a web view. I checked the server-flow in my Xamarin.Forms app, and found you need to enter the Facebook account info for logging. While browsing the mobile app via the browser, the login page would show "Continue as a Name" if I have already logged in to FaceBook (www.facebook.com).

**Note:** When using sever-flow, the page asking for Facebook account is under Facebook domain, Azure would not peek or save your Facebook account info.

> I would like to authenticate Facebook on Azure without entering ID or password, how can I do it?

Based on your scenario, you need to leverage [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) in your mobile app, and you need to install the Facebook app on the device for test. Additionally, you cannot install other apps on the iOS simulator and there may be restrictions on the Android Emulator. So, you generally need to test client flow for social providers on an actual device.

If you integrate the Facebook SDK, then your app will automatically switch to the Facebook app and ask you to approve the authentication request there. For how to integrate the Facebook SDK, you could refer to [Facebook login for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) and [Facebook login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).